# How to view related model attributes

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

How do I view related models when using a "through" relationship in Phoenix Framework?

For example I have a view that shows a normal attribute without any problem:

```
<%= @log.amount %>
```

I also have a relationship to `activities` as defined by:

```
has_many :log_activities, HelloPhoenix.LogActivity
has_many :activities, through: [:log_activities, :activity]
```

How do I access the activities in the view?

If I call `@log.activities` I get an activity. If I call `@log.activities[0].name` or `@log.activities.name` I get an error ("argument error")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the nth item out of a list, you need to use `Enum.at(list, n)` and not `list[n]`. For example, to get the `name` of the first (index 0) item:

```
<%= Enum.at(@log.activities, 0).name %>
```